# You are starting 1 processes in fork_mode without load balancing. To enable it remove -x option

Tags: pm2

I have the following application definition:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "dbm",
            "script": "node_modules/core-dbm/src/app.js",
            "args": "--conf=configuration/local.js --dev",
            "instances": 1,
            "exec_mode": "fork",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "env_production": {
                "NODE_ENV": "production"
            },
            "autorestart": false
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start this configuration, I get the following warning:

> You are starting 1 processes in fork_mode without load balancing. To enable it remove -x option.

I don't understand what it is trying to tell me. Obviously, I don't need load balancing with a single process and I don't have a -x option anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pm2 does not properly check the value of `instances`.

Even though `1` is a perfectly valid setting for running a single instance in fork mode, pm2 does not properly respect it. To get rid of the warning, just remove the `instances` setting.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but am not using any configuration right now as i have fresh installed PM2 and running "pm2 start index.js -i max". Any solution..??